Expansion of a p-form in basis one-forms - antisymmetry of coefficients
I have found the following equation for the expansion of a general p-form in a book:
$\phi = \sum_{i_1<i_2<...<i_p}\phi_{i_1,...,i_p}\sum_{P\in S_p}sgn(P) e^{i_{P1}} \otimes e^{i_{P1}} \otimes ... \otimes e^{i_{Pp}}$ 
where $S_p$ is the group of p-permutations.
The author then says that 'By definition, the coefficients of the expansion obey the antisymmetrization condition $\phi_{Pi_1,...,Pi_p}=sgn(P)\phi_{i_1,...,i_p}$' which is why it is enough to sum over all ordered pairs of indices in the first sum.
However, I don't really get why this has to be the case or what is meant with 'by definition'. p forms are, per definition, alternating in that they change sign under the exchange of any vector arguments, $\phi(...,u,...,v,...) = -\phi(..., v, ..., u, ...)$. But is this relation not already fullfilled due to the second sum, so that the coefficients can be anything?
For example, we can calculate (doing the summation over all indices, i.e. not assuming that the coefficients are antisymmetric)
$\phi(e^1, e^2, e^3) = \phi_{1,2,3}+\phi_{2,3,1}+\phi_{3,1,2}-\phi_{2,1,3}-\phi_{1,3,2}-\phi_{3,2,1}$. Changing the order of, e.g., $e^1$ and $e^2$ automatically gives us a minus sign, so that the coefficients are arbitrary.
Does the author maybe mean that we can $\textbf{define}$ the coefficients in such a way without a loss of generality? Or am I missing the reason why they have to be antisymmetric from the definition of p-forms?

Which book are you using?

@MichaelAlbanese It's called 'Mathematics for physicists' by A. Altland and J. von Delft. So it might be that definitions are different than in real mathematics books

I think there is some confusion between what the authors are denoting $\phi_{i_1,\dots,i_p}$ and the coefficient of $e^{j_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e^{j_p}$. According to the expansion given in the book, the numbers $\phi_{i_1,\dots,i_p}$ are only defined if $i_1 < \dots < i_p$, while it makes sense to ask what the coefficient of $e^{j_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e^{j_p}$ is, regardless of the ordering of the indices $j_1,\dots, j_p$. Let $a_{j_1,\dots, j_p}$ denote the coefficient of $e^{j_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e^{j_p}$ in the expansion of $\phi$.
Example: Consider a two-form $\phi$ on three-dimensional space. Then, according to the expansion, we have
\begin{align*}
\phi &= \sum_{i_1 < i_2}\phi_{i_1,i_2}\sum_{P \in S_2}\operatorname{sgn}(P)e^{i_{P1}}\otimes e^{i_{P2}}\\
&= \sum_{i_1 < i_2}\phi_{i_1,i_2}(\underbrace{e^{i_1}\otimes e^{i_2}}_{P\, =\, \operatorname{id}} - \underbrace{e^{i_2}\otimes e^{i_1}}_{P\, =\, (1\ 2)})\\
&= \underbrace{\phi_{1,2}(e^1\otimes e^2 - e^2\otimes e^1)}_{(i_1,\, i_2)\, = \, (1,\, 2)} + \underbrace{\phi_{1,3}(e^1\otimes e^3 - e^3\otimes e^1)}_{(i_1,\, i_2)\, = \, (1,\, 3)} + \underbrace{\phi_{2,3}(e^2\otimes e^3 - e^3\otimes e^2)}_{(i_1,\, i_2)\, = \, (2,\, 3)}\\
&= \phi_{1,2}e^1\otimes e^2 - \phi_{1,2}e^2\otimes e^1 + \phi_{1,3}e^1\otimes e^3 - \phi_{1,3}e^3\otimes e^1 + \phi_{2,3}e^2\otimes e^3 - \phi_{3,2}e^3\otimes e^2
\end{align*}
so $a_{1,2} = \phi_{1,2},\ a_{2, 1} = -\phi_{2,1},\ a_{1,3} = \phi_{1,3},\ a_{3, 1} = -\phi_{3,1},\ a_{2, 3} = \phi_{2,3},\ a_{3, 2} = -\phi_{2,3}$, and $a_{1,1} = a_{2,2} = a_{3,3} = 0$. Note, there is no $\phi_{2, 1}$, $\phi_{3,1}$, or $\phi_{3,2}$ in the above expansion, but there are $a_{2,1}$, $a_{3, 1}$, and $a_{3, 2}$.
In general, it follows from the expansion that if any two of the indices $j_1, \dots, j_p$ are equal, then $a_{j_1,\dots, j_p} = 0$, and if they are all distinct, then $a_{j_1,\dots, j_p} = \operatorname{sgn}(Q)\phi_{j_{Q1},\dots, j_{Qp}}$ where $Q \in S_p$ is the unique permutation with $j_{Q1} < \dots < j_{Qp}$. For an arbitrary permutation $P \in S_p$, this implies that
$$a_{j_{P1}, \dots, j_{Pp}} = \operatorname{sgn}(QP^{-1})\phi_{j_{Q1}, \dots, j_{Qp}} = \operatorname{sgn}(Q)\operatorname{sgn}(P^{-1})\phi_{j_{Q1},\dots, j_{Qp}} = \operatorname{sgn}(P)a_{j_1,\dots,j_p}.$$
Note, it doesn't make sense to ask for the corresponding property to hold for the numbers $\phi_{i_1,\dots,i_p}$ as they are only defined for $i_1 < \dots < i_p$.

Here's another way of thinking about this using the language in the book. Any tensor $\phi$ of contravariant degree $0$ and covariant degree $p$, i.e. $\phi \in T^0_{\ \ \ p}$, can be written as $\phi = \sum_{j_1,\dots,j_p}a_{j_1,\dots,j_p}e^{j_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e^{j_p}$ for some $a_{j_1,\dots,j_p} \in \mathbb{R}$. If $\phi$ is in fact a $p$-form, i.e. the corresponding multilinear map $V^p \to \mathbb{R}$ is alternating, then the coefficients $a_{j_1,\dots,j_p}$ are very much constrained. First, if any two indices are the same, then $a_{j_1,\dots,j_p} = 0$, while if they are all distinct, then they satisfy $a_{j_{P1},\dots,j_{Pp}} = \operatorname{sgn}(P)a_{j_1,\dots, j_p}$. Let $Q \in S_p$ be the unique permutation such that $j_{Q1} < \dots < j_{Qp}$, and define $\phi_{j_{Q1},\dots,j_{Qp}} = a_{j_{Q1}, \dots, j_{Qp}}$. Now note that $\phi_{j_{Q1}, \dots, j_{Qp}} = a_{j_{Q1},\dots,j_{Qp}} = \operatorname{sgn}(Q)a_{j_1,\dots,j_p}$ and hence $a_{j_1,\dots,j_p} = \operatorname{sgn}(Q)\phi_{j_{Q1},\dots,j_{Qp}}$ as before.
Example: Consider $\phi \in T^0_{\ \ \ 2}$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $\phi(u, v) = (u\times v)\cdot (e_1 + e_2 + e_3)$. Since the cross product is skew-symmetric, so too is $\omega$ and hence it is a two-form. Computing $\phi(e_i, e_j)$ for all $1\leq i, j\leq 3$ gives the expansion
$$\phi = e^1\otimes e^2 - e^2\otimes e^1 - e^1\otimes e^3 + e^3\otimes e^1 + e^2\otimes e^3 - e^3\otimes e^2.$$
So $a_{1,2} = a_{3, 1} = a_{2,3} = 1$, $a_{2,1} = a_{1,3} = a_{3,2} = -1$, and $a_{1,1} = a_{2,2} = a_{3,3} = 0$. As in the previous paragraph, we set $\phi_{1,2} = a_{1,2} = 1$, $\phi_{1,3} = a_{1,3} = -1$, and $\phi_{2,3} = a_{2,3} = 1$. Then $a_{2,1} = -1 = -\phi_{1,2} = \operatorname{sgn}(1\ 2)\phi_{1,2}$, $a_{3,1} = 1 = -\phi_{1,3} = \operatorname{sgn}(1\ 2)\phi_{1,3}$, and $a_{3,2} = -1 = -\phi_{2,3} = \operatorname{sgn}(1\ 2)\phi_{2,3}$. Note, we can rewrite $\phi$ as
\begin{align*}
\phi &= e^1\otimes e^2 - e^2\otimes e^1 - e^1\otimes e^3 + e^3\otimes e^1 + e^2\otimes e^3 - e^3\otimes e^2\\
&= a_{1,2}e^1\otimes e^2 + a_{2,1}e^2\otimes e^1 + a_{1,3}e^1\otimes e^3 + a_{3,1}e^3\otimes e^1 + a_{2,3}e^2\otimes e^3 + a_{3,2}e^3\otimes e^2\\
&= \phi_{1,2}e^1\otimes e^2 + \operatorname{sgn}(1\ 2)\phi_{1,2}e^2\otimes e^1 + \phi_{1,3}e^1\otimes e^3 + \operatorname{sgn}(1\ 2)\phi_{1,3}e^3\otimes 1 + \phi_{2,3}e^2\otimes e^3 + \operatorname{sgn}(1\ 2)\phi_{2,3}e^3\otimes e^2\\
&= \phi_{1,2}(e^1\otimes e^2 + \operatorname{sgn}(1\ 2)e^2\otimes e^1) + \phi_{1,3}(e^1\otimes e^3 + \operatorname{sgn}(1\ 2)e^3\otimes 1) + \phi_{2,3}(e^2\otimes e^3 + \operatorname{sgn}(1\ 2)e^3\otimes e^2)\\
&= \sum_{i_1 < i_2}\phi_{i_1,i_2}(e^{i_1}\otimes e^{i_2} + \operatorname{sgn}(1\ 2)e^{i_2}\otimes e^{i_1})\\
&= \sum_{i_1 < i_2}\phi_{i_1,i_2}\sum_{P\in S_2}\operatorname{sgn}(P)e^{i_{P1}}\otimes e^{i_{P2}}
\end{align*}
which is the expansion given in the book.
In general, one can use similar steps to rewrite $\phi = \sum_{j_1,\dots,j_p= 1}^na_{j_1,\dots,j_p}e^{j_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e^{j_p}$ as $\sum_{i_1 < \dots < i_p}\phi_{i_1,\dots, i_p}\sum_{P \in S_p}\operatorname{sgn}(P)e^{i_{P1}}\otimes\dots\otimes e^{i_{Pp}}$.
